# get teradata tpt job name after script execution

Tags: teradata

I am executing tpt jobs in script 24/7 from powershell with this command

```
cmd /c tbuild.exe -f $tptfile -v $configFile -j $jobname >> $logFile
```

When I check TPT folder for logs it adds job sequence number at the end of my jobname variable so I cannot work with that job. Is there any way how to disable adding job sequence number, or how to get exact job name after execution?

Comment: What do you mean that you "can't work with that job"?

Comment: I want to run twbcmd with job name to terminate it.. I noticed if I am running in paralel 30tpt jobs 24/7 sometimes some of them just hangs so I want to be sure that each job is 100% terminated after run

Comment: You use that sequence # in twbcmd:  `twbcmd <your job id> job terminate`.  The job id is the job name (or user id if you don't specify one) - sequence number.

Comment: I tried that and the problem is that for example I define $jobname = "mytestjob", in TPT folder I see it as mytestjob-234534 what is sequence run number therefore I dont know exact job name
if I put only twbcmd $jobname job terminate I get error that job does not exist

Comment: `twbstat` will list running jobs on the system you execute it on.  It will return the job id, including the sequence number.

Comment: Andrew can you put this as an answer? thats exactly what I needed, run twbstat and grep my jobname variable and I will find exact job id to work with

Comment: but it still doesn't answer the questions that how to get the log name after tpt job has completed